# trouble with aligning elements on website, divs stuck in top left corner, buttons misaligned

Tags: html, css

I researched how to properly line up items in the center of page and got a variety of answers, from doing

```
div {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
```

or

```
div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 }
```

but neither of these worked consistently, or if they did, they would sometimes push other divs (with position: absolute;) into other places, or not work on other browsers. I'm wondering once and for all, how do I get my code to put divs where I want?

For a practical example, my site is at dannyliang.com, and my "More Options" button is stuck in the top left corner, despite "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To center elements on the page, horizontally, there's no need to use `position: absolute;`. Just make sure they are `block` elements. A `div` is already a `block` element by default so you can do it like this:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that this will center relative to the parent container. I guess that's why many people recommended `position:absolute` (to get it out of the flow). I recommend **not** to use `position:absolute` unless you really have to.